# Java txt File from FileWriter is empty

Tags: java

I have trouble with write txt file from class FileWrite in my java project , if the PRINT() method were in VehicleCollection class , and called in main class - don't have problems. But I want print method be in different class which named FileWrite and called  in main method from this class . Here peace of Code . I hope that i  write  correct question. if i should Explain more about my code I will .

I have 3 Classes 1st class is :

```
public class VehicleCollection  {

    private  ArrayList<VehicleInterface> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<VehicleInterface> getArrList() {
        return arrList;
    }

    void  setArrList(ArrayList<VehicleInterface> w){
        arrList = w;
    }

    public void getCollection() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Here Add in ArrayLIst...
    }
}
```

Second class is :

```
public class FileWrite extends VehicleCollection {

    FileWrite(ArrayList<VehicleInterface> w){
        setArrList(w);
    }

    public void print() throws FileNotFoundException {

        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            String text = getArrList().toString();
            File file = new File("krasiWrite.txt");
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new java.io.FileWriter(file));
            writer.write(text);
            ...
        }
```

Third class is main class :

```
FileWrite fw =  new FileWrite();
fw.print();
```

here Have error:cannot be applied to  given types required ArrayList

Comment: Did you `writer.flush()`?

Comment: no only writer.write(text) and write the collection in txt only if method print() were called from Vehicle Collection class

Answer (score 10):

File writes are usually buffered by the operating system. You must either `close()` or `flush()` the writer to make sure that the changes go to disk. If you're done with the file, just close it. A close will automatically flush the buffers.

Comment: And one way to make sure it gets closed is initializing it in a 'try with resources'.

Comment: ok i will flush() but what about the constructor error" cannot be applied to given types required ArrayList"

Comment: Can you cut down the code in your examples to just a few lines around the error, and then also copy and paste the exact error into your question?

Comment: i write this in main class  VehicleCollection veh = new VehicleCollection(); FileWrite fw =  new FileWrite(veh.getArrList());
      fw.print();    and now work

Comment: Good. Are you sure that only calling flush the right thing though? Unless there are special circumstances, explicit flush is usually not required. You should make sure that you close the file.

Comment: OOOO sorry :(  i have close() ... in my project try {
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } ... I dont know that close and flush are replaceble

Comment: "buffered by the operating system". That would probably be fine. But the `BufferedWriter` buffers in Java memory, and that will be lost unless you `flush`/`close` (it never reaches the operating system).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already using Java 7, why not use the try-with-resources construct to avoid having to do things like close streams:

```
try( File   file = new File("krasiWrite.txt"); 
     Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new java.io.FileWriter(file)); )
{ 
     String text = getArrList().toString();
     writer.write(text);
     writer.flush(); // this lines takes whatever is stored in the BufferedWriter's internal buffer
                     // and writes it to the stream
}
catch(IOException ioe) {
   // ... handle exception
}

// now all resources are closed.
```