# My FileWriter file is completely empty

Tags: java, html

Just for your info: I had another question relating to this code, and I had already asked it, I edited the question to this question (completely) but I got no responses.

AIM: I am trying to read in a file(.txt containing HTML) and sort the content. It does create a text file and it completely empty.
I read some similar situations but I have seen their mistake was not adding a out.flush() or out.close() file.

Here is the code till now:

```
import java.io.*;


public class File { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            String input = "SCCM.txt";
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
            String output = "output.txt";
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( output ) );

            String inputLine = "", s="windows";
            String regex = "&nbsp";
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if ( inputLine.contains(s) ) {
                    inputLine.split(regex);
                    out.append( inputLine );
                    out.newLine( );
                }
                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Content I want to sort :

```
<TR class="RowDark">
    <TD width=0><A href="Report.asp?ReportID=100&amp;sp=Service+Pack+1&amp;os=Microsoft%28R%29+Windows%28R%29+Server+2003%2C+Enterprise+Edition"><IMG border=0 src="images/icolink3.gif" alt="Open the target" width=11 height=11></A></TD>
    <TD class=SimpleTextSmall>&nbsp;Microsoft(R)&nbspWindows(R)&nbspServer&nbsp2003,&nbspEnterprise&nbspEdition&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=SimpleTextSmall>&nbsp;Service&nbspPack&nbsp1&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=SimpleTextSmall>&nbsp;60&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
```

Output I want:
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Server 2003 , Enterprise Edition , Service Pack 1 , 60

Stuff I read (for your information):
[Java txt File from FileWriter is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060250/java-txt-file-from-filewriter-is-empty?rq=1)

UPDATE:

```
import java.io.*;
```

public class File {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String input = "SCCM.txt";
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
    String output = "output.txt";
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( output ) );


    try {

        String inputLine = "", s="Windows";
        String regex = "&nbsp";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if ( inputLine.contains(s) ) {
                inputLine.split(regex);
                out.write(inputLine);
                out.newLine( );
            }

        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Hi");

        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

}

UPDATE:

The file DOES output (tons of love to those who helped)

Here is how it is

```
 <TD width=0><A href="Report.asp?ReportID=100&amp;sp=Service+Pack+1&amp;os=Microsoft%28R%29+Windows%28R%29+Server+2003%2C+Enterprise+Edition"><IMG border=0 src="images/icolink3.gif" alt="Open the target" width=11 height=11></A></TD>
            <TD class=SimpleTextSmall>&nbsp;Microsoft(R)&nbspWindows(R)&nbspServer&nbsp2003,&nbspEnterprise&nbspEdition&nbsp;</TD>
```

Any hints/tips/tricks to perhaps make it readable?

Comment: Also be aware that `String.contains()` is case sensitive. Your search string is "windows" but the line you search contains 'Windows'.

Comment: I tried both the suggestions offered but the file is still empty

Comment: You have now searched for "Windows" (capitalized) _and_ moved your close() statements out of the while loop?

Comment: I gave an updated version of the code! Yes, I followed both the steps! :)

Comment: @ToxicGlow You need to place the close statements in a finally block not the exception block as shown below :)

Comment: You didn't put the statements into a finally clause, you put them in the catch.

Comment: Oh, and it still doesn't work - incase you were wondering

Comment: Ohh alright, I will put it in a "finally" block , sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the output stream inside the `while` loop so an `IOException` is thrown almost immediately but the details of the exception are not displayed. These statements

```
in.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

should be in a finally block

```
try {
   ...
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // add me
} finally {
    in.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Only then can you check for the String `Windows` (as mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768472/my-filewriter-file-is-completely-empty#comment32931285_21768472))

```
String s = "Windows";
```

Comment: Curiosity, how did you link to a specific comment like that?

Comment: @Takendarkk the link can be found in the post time e.g 8 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

`inputLine` never contains `windows` however it does contain `Windows`, which causes the the conditional to always evaluate to false, preventing the append method from being called.

Change the following line:

```
String inputLine = "", s="windows";
```

to

```
String inputLine = "", s="Windows";
```

or lowercase `s` before the comparison:

Comment: I tried your suggestion, thanks :) but still my file is empty