# Trying to print out an array as a file?

Tags: java

I've got a maze board in an array but cant seem to figure out how to save it as a txt file and then print it out?

```
String [][] board = new String [][] {
        {"#","#","#"," "," ","#" ,"#","#","#"},
        {"#","#"," ","#"," ","#","#"," ","#"},
        {"#"," "," "," ","#"," "," "," "," "},
        {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#"," ","#"},
    };

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(board));

    File boardFile = new File("board.txt");
    PrintWriter boardPW = new PrintWriter(boardFile);
    boardPW.println(board);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(boardFile);
    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(scan.nextLine());

    }
```

I feel like this is completely wrong but its worth a shot! haha

Comment: `Arrays.toString(board)` doesn't work well with multi-dimensional arrays. Try `Arrays.deepToString(board)` instead.

Comment: just tried it, still not printing haha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java txt File from FileWriter is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060250/java-txt-file-from-filewriter-is-empty)

Comment: If you would dare to research how to ___properly___ write to a file, then you would know why it can't print anything from that.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to point out:

1. when printing out arrays in java, you need to go through them and print each element - printing the name of the array `println(board);` will not give you the desired result.
2. when using Printwriters to write to files, remember to close them.

I also added try/catch blocks, but I assume you used a method that throws Exception?

updated code:

```
    String [][] board = new String [][] {
        {"#","#","#"," "," ","#" ,"#","#","#"},
        {"#","#"," ","#"," ","#","#"," ","#"},
        {"#"," "," "," ","#"," "," "," "," "},
        {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#"," ","#"},
    };

    File boardFile = new File("board.txt");
    try{
        PrintWriter boardPW = new PrintWriter(boardFile);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < board.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < board[i].length; j++){
                boardPW.print(board[i][j]);
            }
            boardPW.println();
        }
        boardPW.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(boardFile);
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```